# Production of Backend Node.js & Express and Frontend with Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I made a web app, for the backend I used Node, js with Express and MySql database, and for the frontend I used the Angular framework.
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99mU7.png)

Everything works locally (to test it I used Mamp and port 3000), but I can't get it to production.
In the service what should I put in place of localhost and port 3000?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { News } from '../models/data.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewsService {

  baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/news';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get<Array<News>>(this.baseURL)

  }
```

[Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KRRE.png)

For the Frontend folder, with the command "ng build --prod --base-href ./." I managed to get it into production and everything is ok.

For the Backend folder, on the other hand, I don't really know how to send it to production, just upload it to the hosting space or is there some command to type?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your exact problem but you should not hard code baseUrl in your code. use config file instead and read that file at runtime using http GET call. By doing this you can deploy your ui on any server and you just need to update config/properties file to match hostname and port number. Same is applicable to backend. MySQL connection parameters should be placed in properties file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build angular with `prod` tag and just copy files to server via `FTP client`

If you want to run your `NodeJS/Express` application to production, better to use suppervisor, maybe `pm2`

```
pm2 start server.js
```

Use `.env` variables for managing configuration.

See:

[Building and serving Angular apps.](https://angular.io/guide/build)

[Run NodeJS with PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the localhost IP. Instead, you've to use the domain name and port (optional) instead of localhost.

Now, how do we implement this?

Make use of `environment.ts`, instead of `baseURL` approach for testing or development environment.

Now, add the domain or hosting URL to `environment.prod.ts`.

While production, the `environment.prod.ts` is automatically made use instead of `environment.ts`.

Example here,

1. environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  _searchAPI: 'http://localhost:3000/search',
};
```

2. environment.production.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  _searchAPI: 'https://your-domain.com/search',
};
```